# How to retrive a cell value from a ASPxGridView in an event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a simple `ASPxGridView` which fires a `OnCustomButtonCallback`
I have tried the following code:

```
protected void grid_CustomButtonCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomButtonCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    MyGridView.Rows[0].Cell[0].Value;
}
```

But it does not see `Rows`: `ASPxGridView does not contain a definition of Rows`

I am using DevExpress. Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'd like to get data from the row in which I clicked the custom button on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve a particular **column/field** values using the [ASPxGridView.GetRowValues](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GetRowValues(System.Int32-System.String--)) method and pass the related row's **VisibleIndex** retrieved from the **EventArgs e.VisibleIndex** property as a parameter:

```
protected void grid_CustomButtonCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomButtonCallbackEventArgs e) {
    var rowValues = grid.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, "FIELD_NAME_HERE");
}
```